# "industry" or "industrial"

Tags: grammar

From VOA Special English:

> Growers get **industry** news along with advice and information from experts.

Why is it "industry" instead of "industrial"? I know that "news" is a noun, and generally in front of a noun is an adjective. But "industry" is just a noun, too. So I think "industrial" may be more agreeable. Can someone tell me why does it use "industry"? Thanks!

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31649/what-is-the-difference-between-electric-and-electrical-and-their-usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, nouns combine together to form noun phrases. The syntax of a noun phrase is a lopsided tree, headed by the rightmost noun, for instance:

> law school admission test

This string of nouns denotes a thing which is a kind of test. More specifically, an admission test: a test to determine suitability for admission. More specifically, a school entrance test: a test to determine suitability of admission to a school. And so on.

Almost all nouns can combine together to make noun phrases, even proper nouns:

> Did you attend the *Paris convention*? [Did you attend that convention which was in Paris?]
>
> That's a real *Jennifer thing* to do! [Jennifer's action is typical of Jennifer's usual behavior.]

The string of nouns only has to make sense, and sense can be established by context. For instance there is no such thing as a "table door", but if you somehow introduce something like that to your audience, they will accept it; in any case, it is not ungrammatical.

It is also important to note that certain combinations of words have entrenched meanings, and it makes a difference whether you use the adjectival form or the noun.

In this particular case, "industry news" is in fact much more correct than "industrial news". The reason is that it is news *about* the industry: writing produced by industry pundits (who, also, are not "industrial pundits").

Something "industrial" is *of* the industry: something used or produced *by* the industry.

A machine, tool, or part can be industrial:

> Our company produces {industrial | industry*} robots.
>
> {Industrial | Industry*} versions of microchips can withstand wider temperature ranges than consumer versions.
>
> My brother-in-law studied {industrial | industry*} engineering, became an {industrial | industry} expert, but ended up working as an {industry | industrial*} journalist.
>
> A truck full of {industry | industrial*} materials overturned on Highway 37, southbound just before exit 53.

Although both "industrial expert" and "industry expert" are used, but they are not necessarily the same thing. My intuition is that an industrial expert might be someone who has knowledge about the processes and materials within some industry (an expert in matters industrial), whereas an industry expert is someone with a broader outlook on an industry as a whole, including perhaps the business side of things (expert in matters concerning the industry).

Comment: I strongly disagree with this statement. ***Almost all nouns can combine together** to make noun phrases, even proper nouns* And the term is ***industrial** engineer*. There's no such thing as an ***industry** engineer*. That's just one example of a pair of nouns that can't be combined. In fact, nearly every single example in the second text box is incorrect. The only one that's completely correct is *industrial materials*. You also can't become an *industry expert* unless you're referring to a **specific** industry.

Comment: Indeed it is not bad grammar; it's non-standard, but that's not bad by default. I'm just adding a native speaker's perspective; you're welcome to disagree. In answer to your comment, **there is** a rule regarding the case you've mentioned: it would be hyphenated. It's a *mining-industry engineer*. Or if you prefer, an *industrial engineer in the mining sector/industry*. I have racked my brain trying to come up with a rule for what constitutes the ability as to what constitutes an attributive noun, but I can't come up with one. Like standard English itself, perhaps it's consensus?

Comment: @JohnQPublic Yep!  Although as in Standard English, there is no strict consensus--native speakers can and do disagree, as we see here.  But I see no problem with *industry* in attributive position, even in your example; an *industry engineer* might be as opposed to a *government engineer*, one who works outside the industry.  (As an aside, there is no rule that *mining industry engineer* must be hyphenated--that's a choice of style, and your preferred style is unfortunately declining in popularity.)

Comment: @snailboat I should know better to say that there are *rules* in English grammar. I didn't say that it's got to be hyphenated; I just said it *would be*. In the NE US, we're taught that whenever nouns, adjectives, or adverbs are used collectively as compound modifiers--that is, when they are one unit whose meaning could be misconstrued--modifying a noun, they should be hyphenated. I'm not shocked to hear that this is in decline though. No, there's nothing wrong with *industry engineer*; I'm specifically referencing standard American **professional** usage, which is why it struck me as wrong.

Answer (score 0):

*Industry* is actually the standard usage. Sometimes nouns can be used to modify other nouns. They're what's known as ***attributive nouns***. And that's what's happening here.

*Industrial news* is OK too, but there's no significant difference in meaning from *news about industry*.

Here's another [example](http://www.merriam-webster.com/help/dictnotes/attrib.htm). And [another](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/blog.php?action=ViewBlogArticle&ba_id=32). And one [more](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsANounAdjunct.htm).

To my knowledge, there's no universal rule as to which nouns can be used attributively. They're also known as [noun adjuncts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

Comment: "Industrial news" sounds to me like news produced by an industrial process.

Comment: @ThePhoton I agree that I don't care for that phrasing, but *industrial news* does still mean *industry-related news.* You can *manufacture news,* but it's not an industrial process unless you're specifically referencing the printing or publishing process. *Manufacturing news* specifically means to fabricate fake stories. But again, I agree that *industry* is much better here.