# What is the difference between "industry use" and "industrial use"?

Tags: phrase-usage

"industry use" and "industrial use" were shown in recent news and discussion rose. However, the argument seemed to focus on  food industry.

Comment: Related Stack Exchange discussions: [industry problems or industrial problems](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193330/industry-problems-or-industrial-problems);  
 ["industry" or "industrial"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13774/industry-or-industrial)

Answer (score 2):

There may be a slight difference in meaning: *industry use* is likely to refer to usage by a particular industry, while *industrial use* would refer to use by any industry.

Hypothetical example:

> Acme Corp. is accused of contaminating the aquifer with uranium tetroxide. Industry use of water has tripled in the last decade.

Here, "industry" would probably refer to the nuclear industry. "Industrial" would include all industries in the affected region.

A kitchen appliance might be labelled "Not for industrial use". The intention is to warn the user that the machine is designed for occasional use, and would not withstand continuous operation.  There, it would be unacceptable to substitute "industry".

Comment: I kind of agree with what you're saying, but I think it's a little misleading to say "industrial use would refer to use by any industry."  "Industrial" is basically a synonym for "factory" or "heavy industry".  Industry is a generic word that means "any business".  It makes perfect sense to talk about "the perfume industry" (the perfume *business*), but "industrial perfume" is kind of meaningless, because perfumes aren't typically associated with factory situations.  (It sounds like the setup for a joke actually -- "you need industrial perfume".)

Comment: @JoeRounceville The question, as I understand it, is about the use of _industrial_ and _industry_ as adjectives.

Comment: Even with that limitation, the definitions apply.  "Industry use" means "use in a type of **business**".  "Industrial use" means "use in a **factory** or **heavy industry**".  For example, in my field, software development, we don't say "These are the proper industrial practices for web development", because software development typically doesn't involve factory work.  Rather, we say "These are the proper industry practices for web development."

Comment: @JoeRounceville If you write that as an answer, I would upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Industrial is an adjective, whereas industry and use are both nouns. In grammar, if a noun modifies another noun,  the modifier serves as an adjective such as home use, chicken soup, industry use. So there is no difference in meaning of these two phrases i.e. industry use and industrial use.